# Is it possible to instruct git to only write packfiles?

Tags: git

I sometimes store git repositories on Flash media, which is slow to create multiple, individual files but fairly quick at writing single large files. The repositories are bare repositories, so it's basically just the `.git` folder.

Whenever I push to these repositories, I notice that git copies a pack file, but then unpacks it. I really don't want git to unpack objects; rather, I want it to keep the objects compressed.

Is there a way to instruct git to only write packfiles and not unpack them?

Comment: Would it be possible to use bundles instead of repositories on your flash drive?

Comment: @Charles: Maybe. Would I still be able to `git push` or do I need to do something different? I haven't used bundles.

Comment: You can't push to a bundle but you can make incremental bundles and you can fetch/pull from bundles once you transfer the flash media to where it's needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewing the [standard config options that git supports](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), I happened to read the following description of `receive.unpackLimit`:

> If the number of objects received in a push is below this limit then the objects will be unpacked into loose object files. However if the number of received objects equals or exceeds this limit then the received pack will be stored as a pack, after adding any missing delta bases. Storing the pack from a push can make the push operation complete faster, especially on slow filesystems. If not set, the value of `transfer.unpackLimit` is used instead.

I configured one of the bare repositories on the Flash drive with `transfer.unpackLimit` set to 0 and a subsequent push of 7 objects did not result in unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an adept of git repacking, but I would try looking at [git-repack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-repack).

> This script is used to combine all objects that do not currently
>   reside in a "pack", into a pack. It can also be used to re-organize
>   existing packs into a single, more efficient pack.
>
> A pack is a collection of objects, individually compressed, with delta
>   compression applied, stored in a single file, with an associated index
>   file.
>
> Packs are used to reduce the load on mirror systems, backup engines,
>   disk storage, etc.

**Edit 1**: maybe the `-a` option is what you're looking for:

> -a
>
> Instead of incrementally packing the unpacked objects, pack
>      everything referenced into a single pack. Especially useful when
>      packing a repository that is used for private development and there is
>      no need to worry about people fetching via dumb protocols from it. Use
>      with -d. This will clean up the objects that git prune leaves behind,
>      but git fsck --full shows as dangling.

**Edit 2**: As I stated in the comment, this is not a real answer, but rather a possible pointer to try with.

Comment: `repack` will repack loose objects but I think you need to describe exactly how it could be used to avoid the unpacking step that normally happens in a push. Unpacking and repacking works in the asker's sitatuation, but it is slow.

Comment: Well, to me `repack` seemed to me a good starting point. I did not meant it as a full answer, but rather as a possible pointer.

Comment: +1 I ended up setting the `transfer.unpackLimit` option, but `git repack -a -d` was still very helpful in cleaning up the loose objects. Thank you.

Comment: From the git manual it seems that `transfer.unpackLimit` is indeed a solution to your problem, but you need to be aware of the fact that even so, after many `push` you'll end up with many packs. If fetching becomes slow, you'll  have to `git repack -a -d` again.

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution for what you'd like to do might be [bup](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup).  The idea of bup is to write git pack files directly (and independently of git) so that you can use the efficient pack file format for backups, without git's performance problems with repacking huge repositories.

An example of how you might create pack files in a remote git repository is given in the "Make a backup on a remote server" example in [bup's README](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup/blob/master/README.md).

As a disclaimer, I haven't tried this myself, so maybe there's some fundamental problem with using bup for your use case, but it seems like a nice idea to me.

Comment: +1 Not quite what I am looking for, but interesting nonetheless. In my case, the git repositories are tracking code bases, and it does not appear that bup can work off of a preexisting git repo.